# How to join more than two tables in sql server query

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, left-join, inner-join

I am creating a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 to find student data from first table, health details from second table and attendance details from the third one. I want to join these tables using left outer or inner join.

The SQL-query is as follows:

```
create proc [dbo].[GetStdProfile]
@Adm_No int
AS
BEGIN   
    SELECT sd.*,hd.*,ad.* 
    FROM Student_Details sd left outer join Health_Details hd left outer join Attendance_Details ad 
    on sd.Adm_No=hd.Adm_No  and sd.Adm_No = ad.Adm_No and hd.Adm_No=ad.Adm_No
END
```

Comment: then what is the problem?

Comment: Read some tutorials first.

Answer (score 2):

Alter your query like this:

```
create proc [dbo].[GetStdProfile]
    @Adm_No int  
BEGIN   
    SELECT sd.*,hd.*,ad.* 
    FROM Student_Details sd 
       left outer join Health_Details hd on sd.Adm_No = hd.Adm_No
       left outer join Attendance_Details ad on hd.Adm_No = ad.Adm_No
END
```

Note: You haven't used the parameter `@Adm_No`. Remove it if not required.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to do a select *, no need to prefix them.  I don't know if you had an issue with running your procedure, but the joins first and ons later got a little screwy.  When you join tables that shared the same field and id, no need to join a single table to multiple tables.  You had hd.Adm_No joined to both sd.Adm_No and ad.Adm_no.  That relationship would easily be filtered out by doing the following:

```
create proc [dbo].[GetStdProfile] 
@Adm_No int 
AS 
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM Student_Details sd left outer join Health_Details hd on 
        sd.Adm_No=hd.Adm_No left outer join Attendance_Details ad  
        on hd.Adm_No = ad.Adm_No 
    Where sd.Adm_No = @Adm_No;
END
```